# Select multiple unnamed ranges with variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to select two unnamed ranges at the same time, that are in non-sequential columns. I am able to highlight two separate columns at once using the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B:B,D:D").Select
```

However, when I try to select ranges in multiple columns using a function to grab the last row, it highlights from B1:Dlrow, instead of B1:lrow and D1:lrow. Here is the code I am using:

```
 Sub selectmultiple()
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    ActiveSheet.Range("B1" & ":B" & lrow, "D1" & ":D" & lrow).Select
End Sub
```

Any help would be grealy appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please note that tags are not keywords.  Stuffing the tag list full of the same words that are in your question (select, multiple, range) will not help categorize it.  **Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!**

Comment: Sorry, first post. But noted going forward, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your comma is in the wrong place it should be inside the quotation marks in the same way that your colons are. Try this...

```
ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B" & lrow & ",D1:D" & lrow).Select
```

Comment: This is missing an ampersand after the first "lrow".

Comment: Thank you both! The above code with the ampersand added in did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Union Method to select multiple range.

```
Sub selectmultiple()
Dim lrow As Long
lrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row


    Union(Range("B1" & ":B" & lrow), Range("D1" & ":D" & lrow)).Select
End Sub
```